# Push Notifications - when the "push server" is personal for each app user (APNS is the issue here)

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have developed an app for an open source home security solution (ZoneMinder). The app I developed is called zmNinja (open source again) - and it works rather well. I am now implementing a mechanism to push notifications (motion detection alarms) to people who will use the app.

After going through the APNS and GCM documents, it looks like the "server" which sends the push to devices must integrate with SSL certificates and API keys generated from Apple and/or iOS. And this, specifically for apple requires a developer account.

Therein lies the predicament. Users of 'zoneminder' install their own servers. There is no central server. I've developed a event server that works with 'zoneminder' on web sockets that can be installed along with zoneminder and it sends notification when there are new alarms. This works very well on Android because Android allows the web socket to be open in background but iOS kills it (I can't treat the socket as VoIP/Location/content-news as its none of the above). Hence I am thinking of how to support APNS in the server. In other words, even if I can't do GCM for Android, there is still a way to receive alarms. No such joy for iOS users.

The problem is that like I described above, I won't be hosting the server. The users of the app will own their own server.

Given this, is there *any* way to support push notifications in IOS without requiring everyone who has their own servers to have apple developer accounts? I assume I can't give my certificates to them either as that would compromise my account.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered setting up your own sentral server, having a web service api, which your clients servers would then talk to in order to send notifications? ie. clients server needs to notify its owner, it talks to your server using a web service api, your server then notifies the central apple server using your certificate, which will then distribute the notification to the persons iphone.

Comment: Also, look at [Prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com/).

Comment: Thanks lasse. Putting up my own server would imply I will have to maintain it and pay for infrastructure. I'm looking for a means to not do that and yet make push notifications possible

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes. I use firebase fcm now.